# HTML Agility and String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, html-agility-pack

I'm usign [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) in C#. I get the attribute value by this code:

```
var butikEndTime = element.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='butik-name']/div[@class='butikTimeLine']/a/div[@class='timelineMain']/h1").GetAttributeValue("enddate", null);
```

This code return attribute like this: `28.9.2015 05:50:00`.

To convert this amount to the Time Stamp will use the following code:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(butikEndTime, "dd.M.yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But receive this error:
`String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Who can help?

Comment: Try replacing "HH" with "hh".

Comment: @Oceans No. This code does not work

Comment: Your issue seems to have nothing to do with HtmlAgilityPack, and that value seems to parse just fine: http://ideone.com/whuPtz Are you sure that `28.9.2015 05:50:00` actually is the value of that `butikEndTime`? Can you show us the XML?

Comment: have you checked the data type of butikEndTime?

Comment: @SumodhS No. What do I do? What is the current type?

Comment: try butikEndTime.GetType()

Comment: @SumodhS Return system.string

Comment: If `butikEndTime` is an actual `System.String` with the value exactly like `28.9.2015 05:50:00` then the conversion he's trying to do should work without any problems. The value of the string must not be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the '.' is not a valid date separator in C#. Try replacing "." with "/" and try to convert the date. I know it's not a good fix. But that's all I can think of now..

```
butikEndTime.replace(".","/");
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(butikEndTime, "dd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion and I've thought of this too but after trying the parse without replacing the dots it ran perfectly for me. So I don't think this will solve his problem. Maybe he should `Trim` any trailing or leading spaces?